# How can I Inject Auto Mapper directly in to Repository Layer, below the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

This is an ASP.net Core 2.1 project.

How can I Inject Auto Mapper directly into Repository Layer? Currently, I have the Auto Mapper being injected into the Controller and then from the controller, I pass it in the constructor to the Repo layer.

It is possible to have it injected directly into Repo or is this the best that I can do?

Here is my startup.ConfigureServices()

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //** other stuff is here



    // Auto Mapper Configurations
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

}
```

Here is a Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{ 
    EmployeesRepo _repo;

    public EmployeesController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _repo = new EmployeesRepo(mapper);
    }

    // GET: Jobs
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO> GetAll()
    {
        //** TODO Fix Later hack for debug
        var employees = _repo.GetLast(100);
        return employees;
    }
}
```

here is a Repo Class

```
public class EmployeesRepo
{
    EFContext db = new EFContext();

    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    // Assign the object in the constructor for dependency injection
    public EmployeesRepo(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return db.Employees.ProjectTo<EmployeeDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();
    }

    internal IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO> GetLast(int v)
    {
       return db.Employees.ProjectTo<EmployeeDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, have your configured mapper registered for your `IRepository<T>` in `ConfigureServices()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the DI framework do the magic for you.

Start by registering everything that needs to be injected:

```
// You can lazily create the IMapper, or if you prefer, use
// a concrete value.
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => mappingConfig.CreateMapper());

// Make your EmployeesRepo implement IEmployeesRepo
services.AddTransient<IEmployeesRepo, EmployeesRepo>();

// I'm guessing but you'll have the connection string somewhere like this.
// Also using a DbContextPool instead has benefits (though not required)
services.AddDbContextPool<EFContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Data")));
```

... then simply:

```
IEmployeesRepo _repo;

public EmployeesController(IEmployeesRepo repo)
{
    _repo = repo;
}
```

...

```
private readonly EFContext _db;
private readonly IMapper _mapper;

// Assign the object in the constructor for dependency injection
public EmployeesRepo(EFContext db, IMapper mapper)
{
    _db = db;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

Comment: I tried, this without using the interfaces and used '            services.AddTransient<EmployeesRepo>();' instead. I am getting 'A suitable constructor for type 'Chopper.Server.Employees.Controllers.EmpoyeesController' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.' error on runtime. Is it required to use an interface?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add the public access modifier before my constructor.

Comment: You _can_ register a concrete type like that and it will work just fine. I would really encourage you to rather use interfaces; aside from many good reasons that I can't do justice in a comment, they are the natural partner of DI.

Comment: Yes I know I am just starting on this project, and changing them to interfaces is easy enough later when I get it more fleshed out. I just wanted to be on the right track now.